# Function that accept all class that inherited from generic in kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, delegates

I'm trying to add `Example` class into a list of `Delegate` through `addDelegate` function. Unfortunately, I got an error :

```
TypeMismatch: Required Delegate<Item, CoreHolder> found Example
```

Here's my code (It's not full code, it just some piece of code that relevant to my question):

```
interface Delegate <T, VH: CoreHolder> {
    fun onCreate(parent: ViewGroup): VH

    fun onBind(items: List<T>, holder: VH)
}

class DelegateManager<T, VH: CoreHolder> {
    private val delegates = mutableListOf<Delegate<T, VH>>()

    fun addDelegate(delegate: Delegate<T, VH>) {
        delegates.add(delegate)
    }
}

class GenericDelegateManager<T> {
    private val delegateManager = DelegateManager<T, CoreHolder> = DelegateManager()

    fun addDelegate(delegate: Delegate<T, CoreHolder>) {
        delegateManager.addDelegate(adapterDelegate)
    }
}

class Main {
    val genericDelegateManager = GenericDelegateManager<Item>()
    fun main() {
        genericDelegateManager.addDelegate(Example())
        genericDelegateManager.addDelegate(Example2())
    }
}

class Example: Delegate<Item, Example.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder: CoreHolder {
        //...
    }
}
class Example2: Delegate<Item, Example2.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder: CoreHolder {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Current workarounds** :
I've found 2 workarounds but I think it's not the best way for doing it,

1. Change the `addDelegate` function's parameter to `Delegate<T, out CoreHolder>` and cast it to `Delegate<T, CoreHolder>` but I got a warning "Unchecked Cast". So the code become

```
    @SurpressWarning("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun addDelegate(delegate: Delegate<T, out CoreHolder>) {
        delegates.add(delegate as Delegate<T, CoreHolder>)     
    }
```

2. Change the `Delegate` interface type parameter to `<T, out VH>` and change `onBind` to `fun onBind(items: List<T>, holder: @UnsafeVariance VH)` so the code become

```
    interface Delegate <T, out VH: CoreHolder> {
        fun onBind(items: List<T>, holder: @UnsafeVariance VH)
    }
```

All those two solutions work, can run and behave as expected. But the code isn’t that fancy.

Is there another better way to solve this kind of problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short - it is impossible to combine these classes to the one `DelegateManager`. The task can be simplified to the following:

```
fun <TKey> someMethod(pair1: Pair1<TKey>, pair2: Pair2<TKey>) {
    val map = mutableMapOf<TKey, ???>()

    map[pair1.key] = pair1.value
    map[pair2.key] = pair2.value
}

class Pair1<TKey>(val key: TKey, val value: String)
class Pair2<TKey>(val key: TKey, val value: Int)
```

As you can see, you couldn't replace `???` to anything, which provides compilable code.

However example can be reworked to:

```
fun <TKey> someMethod(pair1: Pair<TKey, CiImpl1>, pair2: Pair<TKey, CiImpl2>) {
    val map = mutableMapOf<TKey, CommonInterface>()

    map[pair1.key] = pair1.value
    map[pair2.key] = pair2.value
}

class Pair<TKey, TValue: CommonInterface>(val key: TKey, val value: TValue)

class CiImpl1: CommonInterface
class CiImpl2: CommonInterface

interface CommonInterface
```

Finally: you couldn't put `Example` and `Example2` classes into the common collection, the same with my code. Moreover, you couldn't just use `Delegate<?, CoreHolder>`, because it accepts any implementation of `CoreHolder`, which is not acceptable for you.

Comment: thanks for your help, my bad I forgot to mention I didn't include all of the code just the relevant ones. I don't have any problem with the T, my only problem is the VH one. Changing `T` to `in T` won't help.

Comment: @DTechnlogy, am I right, that replacing ```DelegateManager<T, CoreHolder>``` to ```DelegateManager<T, CHT: CoreHolder>``` didn't help too?

Comment: I've updated my post to give you more details and more code that I've tried. Would you mind to help me again? thanks

Comment: Regarding to the code, ```Delegate<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>``` != ```Delegate<T, CoreHolder>```. Why: ```Delegate<T, CoreHolder>``` have function with signature ```fun onBind(items: List<T>, holder: CoreHolder)```, e.g. any CoreHolder implementer should be used in ```onBind```. However ```Delegate<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>``` implements only ```fun onBind(items: List<T>, holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder)```. For example, ```Delegate<T, CoreHolder>``` can accept ```AnotherView.ViewHolder```, however ```Delegate<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>``` couldn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my bad again. I've updated the question. There was an artifact of my previous iteration :bow:

Comment: I need that `addDelegate()` function accept `AdapterDelegate<T, CoreHolder)` (all classes that inherit `CoreHolder` for second type parameter). It was work fine on java by using `<? extends CoreHolder>`. I've read kotlin documentation too and found 2 workarounds to solve it which I've written above